# Where is the error coming from?

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

I'm getting this error but I don't have any idea what I'm doing wrong:

```
>>> runfile('C:/Users/218003107/callphreeqcInput.pyw', wdir=r'C:/Users/218003107')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\218003107\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-
 packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/218003107/callphreeqcInput.pyw", line 5, in <module>
    class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, phreqMDI.Ui_MainWindow):
NameError: name 'phreqMDI' is not defined
>>>"
```

I'm running this code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from phreqMDI import *

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, phreqMDI.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyForm,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self) 
        self.connect(wt1,SIGNAL('textChanged()'),wtResult)
        self.connect(wt2,SIGNAL('textChanged()'),wtResult)
        self.connect(wt3,SIGNAL('textChanged()'),wtResult)
        self.connect(wt4,SIGNAL('textChanged()'),wtResult)


    def wtResult(self):
        if len(self.ui.wt1.text())!=0:
            a=float(self.ui.wt1.text())
        else:
            a=0
        if len(self.ui.wt2.text())!=0:
            b=float(self.ui.wt2.text())
        else:
            b=0
        if len(self.ui.wt3.text())!=0:
            c=float(self.ui.wt3.text())
        else:
            c=0
        if len(self.ui.wt4.text())!=0:
            c=float(self.ui.wt4.text())
        else:
            d=0                      
        sum=a+b+c+d
        self.ui.wt_total.setText(str(sum)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    =MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Here are the first few lines (not showing all 500 lines) of the ui file that created using Qt Designer and converted to .py with pyuic4 (which went fine):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 677)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You want `from phreqMDI import Ui_MainWindow`, and then `class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):`.

Comment: I want to mark this as solved but I don't see a check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've imported all from `phreqMDI`, code should be:

```
from phreqMDI import *
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
```

or

```
import phreqMDI
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, phreqMDI.Ui_MainWindow):
```